# AWS How to use IP from server outside AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, vpn

I have ec2 instance on AWS, what I want it's to use IP from server outside AWS on this instance.

I can setup VPN on server outside AWS and use it with ec2 instance for example.

But what is the better way to do it? Maybe use some VPN-Client service in AWS to connect to my vpn-server and route all traffic from ec2 instance to this VPN connection?

What is the better way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is difficult to understand. What do you mean by "use IP from server outside AWS"? Do you mean that you want to _connect_ to the instance from the Internet? Is the IP address a Public IP address or a Private IP address? Please edit your question to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sorry for misunderstanding, I have 1 server in aws, and 1 server on vps in other country, what I want is that ec2 instance goes online using the IP of the VPS server

Comment: So you are saying that you want the Amazon EC2 instance to be accessed via an IP address that is from outside the AWS ecosystem? Do you need all traffic to be routed/filtered via the external system, or would you be happy for people to go directly to the EC2 instance? Generally, it is best to avoid hard-coding a particular IP address, and instead use DNS to map a name to an IP address so that it can be easily changed. Can I ask _why_ you wish to redirect the IP address in this way? Also, what type of traffic is it serving (HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, etc)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need this so that I can access the Internet with Non-Aws IP on an eс2 instance for web browsing, it is necessary because I need an ip from another country on this instance, not the United States.

So I need all outgoing traffic from the ec2 instance to be routed to the Outside VPN so that I have a different country's IP on the ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

For this task I found that PROXY server is better solution then VPN